# Use list names in sqldf?

Tags: r

Names have been attached to the five elements of a list of dataframes `clusts` as follows:

```
names(clusts) = paste("clust",1:length(clusts),sep="")
```

The names are as desired:

```
print(names(clusts))

"clust1" "clust2" "clust3" "clust4" "clust5"
```

However - as one might guess - those names are limited in scope to the list itself - and in particular are not visible in the global scope :

```
print(ls())

"clusts"  (and others..)
```

This leads to `sqldf` not being able to "see" those dataframes..  Is there a way to make them visible at the global scope (and thus to `sqldf`) ?

**Update** Tried using `with` per comment of @thelatemail :

```
with(clusts,
    meanDfs2<-lapply(clustxs, function(clustx) {
        clust = clustx[[1]]; x = clustx[[2]]
        return(ssql(str('select cid, count(1) cnt from clust',x,' group by cid order by 2 desc')))
    })
)
```

But it does not seem to be working:

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: clust1
```

It was a nice idea though!

Comment: Using `?with` maybe? Like `with(clusts, <sqldf code here>)`

Comment: nice idea! trying it now..    hmm.. does not seem to be working.. seemed like a good idea.. (see updated OP)

Comment: does `fn$sqldf` work for this case?

Comment: not sure I follow: accessing `sqldf` is not the issue . also: what is `fn` here?

Comment: would this work `fn$sqldf(paste0('select cid, count(1) cnt from clusts$clust',x,' group by cid order by 2 desc'))`

Comment: i'm still not sure what is `fn$sqldf` vs `sqldf`.  I did try `clusts$clust1` etc and got this *no such table: clusts$clust1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `envir=` argument of `sqldf` like this:

```
sqldf("select * from clust1", envir = list2env(clusts))
```